# 404 Not Found nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I created a folder in `var/www/html/test`. The folder consists of some PHP files. I am trying access the file like http://example.com/test/test. PHP shows the following error:

> 404 Not Found nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had only one folder: `test`. However, on your URL you are trying to access a `test` folder inside another `test` folder: `test/test`.

So, because the folder `test` inside `test` doesn't exist, the server throws an 404 error (there is no such folder).

If you call: `http://example.com/test/test` what you are really doing is call the file `/test/test/index.html`, `/test/test/index.htm` or `/test/test/index.php`.

Comment: Thanks Tan Bui. Now i am getting the message No input file specified. The URL is example.com/test/test.php.

Answer (score 0):

you missed 'html' forlder in your URL. it should be like this.
http://example.com/html/test/test